# How to create adwords first page bid for keywords?

Tags: python, ads, google-ads-api, adwords-budgetservice

I'm using python for Google AdWords. I need to assign **first page bid** for keywords and ad groups. I can't find a way to set the "first page bid" either using UI or API.